# - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, apache, debian

On Debian Jessie, Apache2 --version "0.91-ubuntu1", PHP 5.6.30.

I have tried many the questions already answered when searching for the topic.

1) I did the manual install for MongoDB PHP Driver
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

2) To check if it works I created a file testMongo.php and added

> < ?php phpinfo(); ?>

3) Running testMongo.php in the browser yield that configuration file can be found in.

> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

4) My mongo.so file can be located using the command

> php -i | grep extension_dir

5) Output is:

> extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20131226 => /usr/lib/php5/20131226

6) In this file I added right after "Dynamic Extensions"

> extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so

7) I then went over to [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and did the Command-line installation

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

8) Once Composer is installed I tried:

```
php composer.phar require mongodb/mongodb
```

However this results in the following message:

```
  Problem 1
   - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
   - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
   - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
   - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.2 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.2.0].
```

Some fellows mentioned in a post that I could use --ignore-platform-reqs
It works!

When i run:

> # php5 index.php
>
> $client = new MongoDB\Client(< connection to mongo-atlas>) //Works with python

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' 
not found in /var/www/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 83
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Composer is giving you the right answer there, you are using the wrong library.
Don't use --ignore-platform-reqs, or you can, which to force install it.
What you need to do now is check which library fits your php version. Write

> php --version

if you don't know which one you are using. Output should be something like:

```
PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 09:49:20)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Find your version in the list below.

See the description in mongodb: [PHP-Driver for mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/?_ga=2.210371221.1827438998.1511032572-19439424.1507887238#reference-compatibility-mongodb-php)

[image: Driver compatibility]

Head over to [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) and download whichever version fits your php version number.

in your case (PHP5.6):

```
$ wget https://pecl.php.net/get/mongodb-1.2.11.tgz
$ tar -xvzf mongodb-1.2.11.tgz
$ cd mongodb-1.2.11/
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make all -j 5
$ sudo make install
```

now it should work.

You can test the php mongodb connection with this code (finding an ObjectId) :

```
<?php
# filename ConnectMongo.php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// connect to mongodb
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://username:password@host');

$id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("5a0c8e2362eb6404c2f10032");
$filter = ['_id' => $id];
$options = [];

$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$rows   = $manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);
foreach ($rows as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
?>
```

In terminal write this to test the connection:

> $ php ConnectMongo.php

Make sure that you also install using composer, you should not get that same error anymore.

Comment: Hello @mattis, did u tried this example in php 7.0.

Comment: I don't remember specific, but I think I have. Also the example above indicates that 7.1 is available.

Comment: I am implementing this example in 7.0 wamp. it is not working.

Comment: Ok. That's a bit of topic, given that this question here assumes Linux (Debian Jessie). You probably could figure it out in Windows, but if you plan on doing this a lot, I would recommend getting a Linux distribution. I always use https://www.digitalocean.com to create a simple linux droplet with all necessary apps installed.

Answer (score 8):

Run

```
pecl upgrade mongodb
```

If it complains about phpize, run

```
sudo apt install php7.x-dev
```

Replace 7.x with your PHP version. E.g. -

```
sudo apt install php7.3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my time. Pecl upgrde mongodb does the trick

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [Mongodb extension page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php) in PHP.net

As of Ubuntu 20.04, php-mongodb in the database is outdated and you'll need the PECL method to install latest version of MongoDB.

To do this in Ubuntu, you'll need the php-pear plugin and php-dev:
sudo apt install php-dev php-pear

then you can run: `sudo pecl install mongodb`

Answer (score -2):

You can try with this flag: 
   --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: That does not solve the problem. It only hides the errors and continues.

Comment: This would not solve the problem. I will suggest you delete this response so it doesn't get you more negative votes