# Problem with installation of MongoDB-odm on Symfony 6

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck with a problem of MongoDb installation.
I'm working with Symfony 6 and PHP 8.1, and i would like integrate in my application mongoDB. I've downloaded the mongoDB image on Docker, and all is working.

***The problem***

Now, i need to use doctrine for MongoDB. So, follow the  [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-bundle/en/4.4/installation.html#installation) , i run `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` and also `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm` . For the first command, i get the following errors:

> Problem 1
> - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[4.3.0, ..., 4.3.1] require doctrine/persistence ^1.3.6|^2.0 -> found doctrine/persistence[1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 2.0.0, ..., 2.5.7] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.1).
> - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[4.4.0, ..., 4.5.2] require ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
> - Root composer.json requires doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ^4.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[4.3.0, ..., 4.5.2].
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\xampp\php8\php.ini
> You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
> Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mongodb` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

And for the second one:

> You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
> Using version ^1.0 for doctrine/mongodb-odm
> Running composer update doctrine/mongodb-odm
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
> - doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.8] require symfony/console ~2.3|~3.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
> - doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.1.0, ..., 1.3.7] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Root composer.json requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.7].

As you can see, in the first error message he trying to say me that i have some packages not compatible with the installation of mongo's extension. In the second, with the default command installation, he's trying to install 1.0 version instead 2.4.*!

***What i've tried?***

So, i tried to 'force' the installation. I've insert `"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^2.4.0"` in the *composer.json* , followed by `composer update doctrine/mongodb-odm`  and i still get the error:

> Problem 1- Root composer.json requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^2.4.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3].
> - doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.4.0, ..., 2.4.3] require ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.

***What i suppose?***

Maybe can be the extension of mongo DB in the php.ini file, but i ve installed mongoDB also on windows and added the extension in the php.ini file, but nothing is changed.

Any ideas?
Thx

Comment: Please add all error messages in text form, along wiht your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, how did you try to install the extension? Installing it on Windows won't make it available to any Docker image

Comment: @NicoHaase Done. Yes, but when i saw the message related to php.ini, i thought that can be this the problem. I tried with PECL https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/

Comment: Please share how you tried to enable the extension to the Docker container

Comment: I have php in local, on Docker i have just the Mongo image. So i don't have PHP on docker, how can i enable the extension on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272688/mongodb-mongodb-1-2-0-requires-ext-mongodb-1-3-0-the-requested-php-extensi could help, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597994/installing-mongodb-driver-php-7-2-3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the MongoDB drivers. So, what i did is:

- Download the MongoDB package with DLL included.
- Copy the DLL extension of Mongo inside php/ext folder
- execute `pecl install mongodb`

For the next, follow this [Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/).